# Calculate the mean of the minimum of any k samples

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics, order-statistics

Given a fixed list of `N` numbers from an unknown distribution, and a `k` (`k <= N`), say we would like to take the minimum value from a sample of size `k`.

How can one find the mean (or median) of the minimum of any possible sample of size `k`? Is it possible to compute this without having to calculate all possible samples or at least approximate it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we make any assumptions about the distribution of the numbers? Are they normal, uniform, binomial, etc? Are you asking for some kind of necessary general property? Are you asking if simply taking the numbers that meet your criterion & calculating their mean is unbiased or consistent?

Comment: The distribution of the numbers is unknown. I have some real world, real-valued data for which no distribution fits with confidence so I'm looking for some general method to compute the mean or meadian, if possible, not necessarily to define properties of it. Please correct me if I'm not posting with the correct tags or something, this is my first post on cross validated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understood your question well, but you could perform Monte Carlo simulations and average the results. As soon as it doesn't change dramatically from one iteration to another, this is probably a good approximation. See the example bellow, in R:

```
minVector=matrix()
meanMinVector=matrix()
nIter = 800
allNumbers = runif(100,min=0, max=10)

for (ii in c(1:nIter)){

  nSample = sample(allNumbers,10)
  minVector = c(minVector,min(nSample))
  meanMinVector = c(meanMinVector,mean(minVector, na.rm = TRUE))
}
plot(meanMinVector, type="l")
```

See bellow that the value converges well with few hundreds iterations:

[image]

Please, let me know if my answer was useful for you :)

Comment: Thanks @bernardo-aflalo. This will indeed give a good approximation of this and is what we are currently using, but I wonder if there is a more accurate way to directly calculate the value.